# WPF - Unclear behavior of a Popup on a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, tabcontrol

I created a autocomplete textbox as a user control in WPF. I was using a popup to ensure that my listbox is always on the top of other controls.

I realized an unclear behavior if I place the user control on different TabItems of a TabControl.

I created a simple example to illustrate that. I place a popup on two differnt tabcontrols with identical XAML.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab_0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="ParentTextBox_Tab_0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Popup Name="PopupTest_Tab_0" IsOpen="True" 
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName = ParentTextBox_Tab_0 }" 
                   Placement="Bottom">
                <TextBox Name="PU_TextBox_Tab_0" Text="PU_TextBox_Tab_0-Text"/>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab_1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="ParentTextBox_Tab_1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Popup Name="PopupTest_Tab_1" IsOpen="True" 
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName = ParentTextBox_Tab_1 }" 
                   Placement="Bottom">
                <TextBox Name="PU_TextBox_Tab_1" Text="PU_TextBox_Tab_1-Text"/>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

When I now enter the **Tab_0**, the popup is **shown**.
[image]

When I enter **Tab_1**, the popup is **not shown**.
[image]

When I return to **Tab_0**, the pop is **not shown anymore**.
[image]

Can anyone help to explain the reason of that behavior?

**UPDATE 1**

Based on the comment below, I added the following:

```
private void ParentTextBox_Tab_0_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupTest_Tab_0.IsOpen = true;
}

private void ParentTextBox_Tab_1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupTest_Tab_1.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Nevertheless - when I enter the Tab1 the first time (and the GotFocus method is called), the popup does not show.

When I return to Tab0, with the GotFocus handler, the popup is shown.

That is exactly the issue I am facing with my user control (keep in mind the code here is just a simple example).

**UPDATE 2**

With that code it works - but that doesn't make sense anyway for me...

```
private void ParentTextBox_Tab_1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupTest_Tab_1.IsOpen = false;
    PopupTest_Tab_1.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: You hardcoded the `IsOpen` Property to `True`. As soon as popups lose the focus their `IsOpen` property gets automatically set to `False`. You will have to do that dynamically. For example in the `GotFocus`event of the `TextBox`
[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview) describes the element further.

Comment: @Eric.Volli  Thanks for your reply. Nevertheless I do not understand the different behavior in Tab0 and Tab1

Comment: ok sry for the misunderstanding. If you put both of the textboxes into the first tab both are shown. So I think the second isn't open because the Tab1 is not shown on launch and then the popup does not get redrawn on the opening of the Tab1.

I played around with a Grid.Loaded event in Tab1:
`Console.WriteLine("GridLoadedEventinvoked");

Console.WriteLine(PopupTest_Tab_1.IsOpen.ToString());
 
PopupTest_Tab_1.IsOpen = false;
 
PopupTest_Tab_1.IsOpen = true;
`
The code says that the popup is open. Setting IsOpen=false and then to true again opens it. I think it's a "refresh" problem.

Comment: @Eric.Volli - yeah, based on your comment I just figured it out by myself (see above) - anyway many thanks for the hint...

Comment: Mhh not happy with that solution. Sorry that I cannot help more.